# Redefine the infix operators

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am learning [Jason Hickey's Introduction to Objective Caml](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf).

Just have a question about **Redefine the infix operators**.

---

So in the book, there is such a paragraph:

```
# let (+) = ( * )
      and (-) = (+)
      and ( * ) = (/)
      and (/) = (-);;
  val + : int > int > int = <fun>
  val - : int > int > int = <fun>
  val * : int > int > int = <fun>
  val / : int > int > int = <fun>
# 5 + 4 / 1;;
-: **int = 15**
```

---

**First, how does these redefinition work?**

To me, it seems the functions are running in a kind of indefinite loop, because all the operations seem redefined and connected.

for example, if I do `1+2`, then it will be `1 * 2` and since `( * ) = (/)`, it will be then `1 / 2` and since `(/) = (-)`, then it will be `1-2`, so on so forth. **Am I right?**

---

**Second, will the result of `5 + 4 / 1` be `15`, even if the functions are executed only one step further in the redefinition?**

So assume the redefinition will be execute one step further, i.e., `1 + 2` will only be `1 * 2` and no more transform, so `5 + 4 / 1` should be `5 * 4 -1`, right? then the answer is `19`. **Am I correct?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To me, it seems the functions are running in a kind of indefinite
>   loop, because all the operations seem redefined and connected.

Not really, it's just a simultaneous re-definition of infix operators (with the `and` keyword). What you see is **not** a recursive definition. In OCaml, recursive definitions are made with **let rec** (as you may already know).

For the second part of the question, I think it's a matter of **operator precedence**. Note that in the original expression `5 + 4 / 1` is actually `5 + (4/1)` following the usual precedence rules for arithmetic operators. So, I think the conversion simply preserves this binding (sort of). And you get `5 * (4 - 1) = 15`.

Comment: So you mean if I use **let rec**, then the answer is different? I mean it will be what I imaged?

Comment: @JacksonTale: Yes, but you won't be able to use `rec` for this definition as it is (I tried, the compiler didn't like it). instead, you'll have to do `let (+) x y = x * y and ...`. But you are correct about the outcome, I re-defined the operators that way and it went into a loop. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The key observation (IMHO) is that `(+)` is being defined by the *preexisting* definition of `( * )`, not by the one that appears a few lines later. Similarly, `( * )` is being defined by the *preexisting* definition of `(/)`. As Asiri says, this is because of the use of `let` rather than `let rec`.

It's also true that in OCaml, precedence and associativity are inherent in the operators and can't be changed by definitions. Precedence and associativity are determined by the first character of the operator.

If you look at the table of operator precedences and associativities in [Section 6.7 of the OCaml Manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html), you'll see that all the entries are defined for "operators beginning with character X".

Comment: +1, I think even if we change the "meaning" of `+` by re-defining it, we cannot change it's associativity, which is determined by the static form of the expression (as governed by the table you pointed out). Cheers!

Comment: Right, both precedence and associativity are fixed, based on the first character of the operator. I'll update my answer.